# Classes folder shows up in Build Path but not Project Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath, web-inf

I need to put a compiled class into WEB-INF/classes. My WEB-INF folder didn't have a classes folder so I created one according the directions [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/474423/vc/ecplise-doesn-create-classes-folder).

Even after restarting my computer, however, the classes folder won't show up in the project explorer (even though it is in the Build Path).

[image: Build path WITH classes file]

[image: Project Explorer WITHOUT classes]

Also, for extra happiness/brownie points, can you tell me how to compile just one class to my classes folder?

Thanks all!

Comment: did you check the filter settings of the project explorer? maybe some setting is hiding that folder

Comment: Yup! That fixed it. If you want to make that an answer.... :)

Comment: hehe it's okay was rather a blind guess than a real answer ;)

Comment: See also: [Eclipse Mars - imported projects don't show up in Project/Enterprise Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45465437/4561887)

Answer (score 1):

Let me make the discussion little transparent, goto view menu(in project explorer top right corner) ----> customize view ----> uncheck java output folders.